# WebSphere 7.0 run configuration for eclipse 3.7 (no plugin)

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, websphere, websphere-7

I am using ecdlipse 3.7 - indigo.
I wish to work with WebSphere Application Server v7.0, but I don't want to use the plugin since it's currently in beta stage. 
So, I want to create a regular java runtime configuration.

I tried to open the startServer.bat and look at the java call it makes, however this wan't successful, as not all of the log entries created by the server were redirected to the eclipse console.

By the way, if I had the plugin, could I somehow retrieve the underlying java command it activates? -- so that I can make the run configuration out of it?

Can anyone help?

Thank you.